# UFW settings on Ubuntu 16.04 serving a MySQL database to a few web servers

Tags: mysql, iptables, ufw

I am setting up an Ubuntu 16.04 server that will be used exclusively for incoming and outgoing MySQL database requests to/from some web servers.

Using UFW I am wondering if I could block everything and then make exceptions. Some older notes I took suggested:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
```

After I make the entries, ufw status doesn't display anything concerning those rules.

And then:

```
sudo ufw allow mysql
sudo ufw allow OpenSSH
sudo ufw allow 2222/tcp
sudo ufw allow from 012.34.567.89 comment ip's of web servers
```

I'm getting:

```
Host 'pool-012-34-567-89.area.fios.verizon.net' is not allowed 
to connect to this MySQL server
```

How do I fix that? And, is there any magic to the order of the rules?

UPDATE:
I had already set up users with privileges:

```
CREATE USER 'usr'@'web-server_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'usr'@'web_server_ip';
```

My ssh port is something other than port 22. "2222" is just an illustration.

Comment: The message you are receiving is coming from the MySQL server, not iptables or ufw.  You're on to the next part, granting permissions in MySQL.

Comment: I'm responsible for the second downvote.  I'm downvoting because you're spending your time complaining about others actions instead of trying to solve the problem yourself.  If you copy and paste your error message into google (removing your hostname, because that changes.. obviously) you'll get hundreds of thousands of results, none of which you've mentioned here.  This question started as a question about ufw which you've done nothing to improve but add an error message and a mysql tag.  I also put in a close vote due to the last one.  Nothing classic about me!

Comment: See update above. I've searched google ad nauseum.

Comment: You should delete this question and form a new one based on your new understanding.  This isn't an interactive helpdesk, it's a question and answer site.

Comment: @yoonix the connection was working fine with the user and privileges that were created before I created the ufw rules. The problem occured after creating ufw rules. The error message has weird syntax... dashes where periods would normally be.

Comment: @Jay That is not an IP address in the error - it's the PTR record for your IP address, which is a DNS record.

Comment: Additionally, it's incredibly foolish to make *any* database server available over the public internet. If your web and db servers cannot be co-located (where they can communicate over a secure LAN), then you should stand up a VPN so they can communicate securely.

Comment: @EEAA great suggestion. This is a stop gap measure for development. The public IP's will be replaced with private IP's when my host fixes a problem that is preventing me from using them. All my servers are in the same datacenter. My host offers internal private IP's for this purpose but they are not working at the moment. I need a short term solution to keep another developer going.

Answer (score 2):

What's your ssh port? You probably just need one of the following: the rule "ssh" is the same as the 2222 one but for port 22. And more, if you already allowed ssh and mysql on a mysql db server why would you explicitly allow the server's ips. You already opened 3306 globally! And no. There's no "magic" in the order of ufw's rules.

The error you added to your edit means that the mysql account you created is not allowed to connect from the mentioned host.

You have to create per host accounts, or very insecurely allow an account to connect from any host using the % wildcard.

If you want to implement a mysql db server you'd better read documentation!

After your Update 2 I have to say that you either didn't actually do what you wrote or pool-....verizon.net is not the same host you added in mysql create user statement. Try to create another user with another name and do it twice, with both hostname and IP address, and same password of course, and if you don't mess anything it **MUST** work.

And again, read documentation. At this time, you may already have done at least 3 errors, about partitioning and mounting, db server's configuration, and too loose firewalling, and the fourth was permission granting.

Comment: i put an update in above.

Comment: Thank you. It is late so I'll follow through on your suggestion to create two new users. Also, my host is working on getting the private IP's working. My understanding is that a connection inside the same datacenter poses a much smaller degree of risk. Do you agree with that? Also, the connection is encrypted using MySQL's encryption utility.